# How to make RecyclerView show items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am really struggling with understanding how the RecyclerView works.
I have already made the adapter and the main code for it but it shows nothing.

I already tried a couple of things but none worked since I have no idea what I am doing.
Also, I already made a custom layout for it so if possible I would like to use that

Little bit of an edit:

I also checked if the php code in Postman to see if that was the problem and it all went fine and I got all the data I need so the problem is with the android code.
This is the adapter:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CardItem> data;
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView title;
        public TextView price;
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutTitle);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutPrice);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutImage);
        }
    }
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<CardItem> arr){
        data = arr;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(cardView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int pos){
        CardItem item = data.get(pos);

        TextView title = holder.title;
        TextView price = holder.price;
        ImageView image = holder.image;

        title.setText(data.get(pos).getTitle());
        price.setText(data.get(pos).getPrice());
        /**
        image.setImageBitmap(data.get(pos).getImage());
         **/
    }
    public int getItemCount(){
        return data.size();
    }


}
```

This is the Home Fragment:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Home extends Fragment {
    TextView text;
    RecyclerView container;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<CardItem> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arr);
        container.setAdapter(adapter);
        container.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        loaditems();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
       return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    }

    void loaditems(){
        String url = "http://192.168.108.2/createdb/GetAllOffers.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONArray jsonArray_users = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("offers");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_users.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_users.getJSONObject(i);
                                arr.add(new CardItem(jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("desc"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("price"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("madeby"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("uuid")));
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        text.setText(error.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
    }
```

This is the CardItem class:

```
package com.example.create4me;

import android.content.Intent;

public class CardItem {
    //private int mImageResource;
    private String title, desc, price, madeby, uuid;

    public CardItem(
                    String title,
                    String desc,
                    String price,
                    String madeby,
                    String uuid){
        //this.mImageResource = image;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.price = price;
        this.madeby = madeby;
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }
    public String getUuid(){
        return this.uuid;
    }
    /**
    public int getImage(){
        return this.mImageResource;
    }
     **/
    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }
    public String getDesc(){
        return this.desc;
    }
    public String getPrice(){
        return this.price;
    }
    public String getMadeby(){return this.madeby;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding a new `CardItem` to `arr`, you also might wanna call `loaditems();` in `onViewCreated()` instead to avoid any additional problems

Answer (score 0):

In order to show new items, you need to inform your adapter that new data has been attached. To do so, you should notify your adapter in the following way:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

In your particular case, you need to do this after the for-loop which populates declared `ArrayList<CardItem>`

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_users.length(); i++) {
    // here populate arr with items
}
// notify adapter about new items
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Didn't work for some reason, I updated the code in the question so maybe something will come up.

Answer (score 0):

1. call `loadItems` method at the end of `onViewCreatedMethod`.
2. you should add a method into the adapter for changing data and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
   follow this code:

```
public void setData(ArrayList<CardItem> data){
    this.data = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

3. call above method after adding items in `arr` in your fragment(after for loop).like this:

`adapter.setData(arr);`

final adapter code is:

```
class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CardItem> data;
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView title;
        public TextView price;
        public ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutTitle);
            price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutPrice);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardLayoutImage);
        }
    }
    public RecyclerAdapter(ArrayList<CardItem> arr){
        data = arr;
    }
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        // Inflate the custom layout
        View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cardlayout, parent, false);

        // Return a new holder instance
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(cardView);
        return viewHolder;
    }
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int pos){
        CardItem item = data.get(pos);

        TextView title = holder.title;
        TextView price = holder.price;
        ImageView image = holder.image;

        title.setText(data.get(pos).getTitle());
        price.setText(data.get(pos).getPrice());
        /**
         image.setImageBitmap(data.get(pos).getImage());
         **/
    }
    public int getItemCount(){
        return data.size();
    }
    public void setData(ArrayList<CardItem> data){
        this.data = data;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

final fragment code is:

```
public class Home extends Fragment {
    TextView text;
    RecyclerView container;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<CardItem> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        container = view.findViewById(R.id.homeContainer);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(arr);
        container.setAdapter(adapter);
        container.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
        loaditems();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);
    }

    void loaditems(){
        String url = "http://192.168.108.2/createdb/GetOffer.php";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                            JSONArray jsonArray_users = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("offers");
                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray_users.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray_users.getJSONObject(i);
                                arr.add(new CardItem(jsonObject.getString("title"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("desc"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack1title"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack2title"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack3title"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack1desc"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack2desc"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack3desc"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack1price"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack2price"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("pack3price"),
                                        jsonObject.getString("uuid")));
                                text.setText(arr.get(0).getTitle().toString());
                            }
                            adapter.setData(arr);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        text.setText(error.getMessage().toString());
                    }
                });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure get data from the server? check the size of arr after For loop.

Comment: Yeah everything seems fine, just doesn't show any items. Is there a way to set the layout? I think the layout I made isn't set to the RecyclerView and that's why it's not working.

Comment: please share your XML file.(home.xml)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I found the answer. First off, kudos to the people who told me to add the
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the `for` loop.

Secondly, apparently my data was wrong, instead of

```
arr.add(new CardItem(jsonObject.getString("title"),
                     jsonObject.getString("desc"),
                     jsonObject.getString("price"),
                     jsonObject.getString("madeby"),
                     jsonObject.getString("uuid")));
```

I was supposed to write

```
arr.add(new CardItem(jsonObject.getString("title"),
                     jsonObject.getString("description"),
                     jsonObject.getString("price"),
                     jsonObject.getString("madeby"),
                     jsonObject.getString("belongto")));
```

Kinda my mistake there. But thanks to anyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

With all above changes, also try to add
container. hasFixedSize(true) ;
in home fragment.
I think it should work properly